# Django: filter to check if both/multiple fields are in list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model ModelNameHere in Django with the fields field_a and field_b.
I have a list in python with tuples of the form (a,b)

I want to get all instances of the Django model where both fields are in the Python list.

If there was only one field, this would be simple:

```
my_filter_list = [a1, a2, a3]
ModelNameHere.objects.filter(field_a__in=my_filter_list)
```

But for multiple fields, this does not work

```
my_filter_list = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3)]
ModelNameHere.objects.filter( ? )
```

Is there a way to check both fields at the same time?

Alternatively, is there a way to turn my_filter_list into a temporary table so that I can join that table with ModelNameHere using both field_a and field_b as the join key?

edit:

A quick addition: I have an index set on field_a, but not on field_b.

Comment: Have you thought about putting all this logic into a custom QuerySet class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension for the query kwargs and use a pipe operator for OR operation on querysets.

```
query_fields = ({ 'field_a': value_a, 'field_b': value_b } for value_a, value_b in my_filter_list)

queryset = ModelNameHere.objects.none()
for query_kwarg in query_fields:
    queryset |= ModelNameHere.objects.filter(**query_kwarg)
queryset = queryset.distinct()
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you know what the resulting SQL would look like? Does it optimize like it would for a join between two tables, or will this create len(my_filter_list) many queries and UNION them?

Comment: Django QuerySets are lazy, it won't be executed until it is evaluated. `filter()` method only just accumulate all the queries into a single query. A single query would be executed when the `queryset` is evaluated, (ie, when you loop over the `queryset`)

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that poorly: I know there will be only one query, but will that query have the form '(SELECT ... ) UNION (SELECT ...) UNION ...'?
Actually, I don't think I know enough about what the database does to know if this would be faster or slower than any alternative solution :-(

Comment: No, there won't be any UNION queries, but more like a series of LEFT OUTER JOIN queries which depends on the condition you provide query_fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your `my_filter_list` variable is not anticipated to be too long (as you may run into performance issues), you could construct a [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) query as such:

```
from django.db.models import Q

multi_field_filter = None
for field_a_val, field_b_val in my_filter_list:
    # logical AND the two field values together
    q = Q(field_a=field_a_val, field_b=field_b_val)
    # logical OR the AND'd terms together
    multi_field_filter = q if multi_field_filter is None else (multi_field_filter | q)

results = ModelNameHere.objects.all()
if multi_field_filter is not None:
    results = ModelNameHere.objects.filter(multi_field_filter)
```

**For much longer lists**, one wouldn't want to generate copious amounts of SQL to be able to do these kinds of queries. One (possibly hacky) solution could also involve adding an extra field to your model which concatenates the two values in a searchable way, like so:

```
class ModelNameHere(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IntegerField()
    field_b = models.IntegerField()
    fields_concat = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, db_index=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # automatically update on save
        self.fields_concat = "%s.%s" % (self.field_a, self.field_b)
        # call parent save
        super(ModelNameHere, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, when you want to look up your specific combinations, just do an exact text search match:

```
# using set() automatically deduplicates any search combinations
concat_filters = set([
    ("%s.%s" % (field_a_val, field_b_val)) for field_a_val, field_b_val in my_filter_list
])
# do your lookup here
results = ModelNameHere.objects.filter(fields_concat__in=concat_filters)
```

Comment: What do I do if len(my_filter_list) is too long? Is there an alternative that lets Django understand that it can optimize the query?

Comment: len(my_filter_list) should be around 1000 or so in practice, but there could always be outliers. Actually, I'm not sure right now, but will the query you gave let Django form an optimal SQL query assuming that A is indexed? I'm not sure how concatenated boolean filters compare performance wise to a join between two tables on a=a AND b=b (assuming I turned my_filter_list into a table first).

Comment: With over 1,000 items, none of the currently proposed solutions will be optimal (in terms of the SQL they generate, as the queries will be massive). My solution here would work if you had 10 to 20 items, perhaps. I'll try think of another alternative for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **enumerate** , Like this with the Combination of Q :

```
from django.db.models import Q
result_list = []
my_filter_list = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3)]

for n,m in enumerate(my_filter_list):
    query_set = ModelNameHere.objects.filter(Q(field_a=n[0]) | Q(field_b=m[0]))
    if query_set.count() >0:
        result_list.append(query_set)
```

Comment: this would result in len(my_filter_list) many queries though, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, Just one time. Total queries will be same in all cases. It will query for each item of the list only one time. Which is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @FlorianDietz This is as an optimized solution as others. Please rethink the iterations.

Comment: But won't it send len(my_filter_list) many separate queries, while the other solution only send one query? The runtime should be the same in O(n), but there might be a lot of overhead from translating so many queries into SQL and asking the database to execute them.

Comment: @FlorianDietz Yes. But that's the requirement, you need to check each and every value of both fields and it will not always compute the whole query, if the first condition is true, OR does not check the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

[Annotate a field which combines both values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#concat):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Value

my_filter_list = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3)]
separator = ' '
ModelNameHere.objects.annotate(
    a_b=Concat('a', Value(separator), 'b')
).filter(
    a_b__in=['{}{}{}'.format(a, separator, b) for a, b in my_filter_list]
)
```

The good thing is that it's a single query and is easy to understand.

The bad thing is that you will get not only (a1, b1) and (a2, b2), but also (a1 b1, ) and ( , a1 b1). If it's critical to you, use something more complicated as a separator (':', for example).